# Sending Post Request to RESTful WCF Service

Tags: c#, java, android, wcf, android-async-http

I was working on my android project with my friend and we stucked at some point. I'am trying to make an async post to WCF rest web service and on the service side, I'm inserting the data into db. I'm sending the data via JSON object. I open a dialogue box and when the request is done successful, dialogue box disappears. Now my problem is, I cannot make post request, actually, I don't get any error but it seems there is a problem. There is no problem on get request. I'm going to crazy, so I need your help. Here my codes

Thank you

**JAVA**

```
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity3.this, "Please wait ...",  "Task in progress ...", true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        jarray = new JSONArray();
        json2 = new JSONObject();

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        try {

            json2.put("CreateDate", "30.03.2014 15:30:00");
            json2.put("EventCategory", "Yemek");
            json2.put("EventID", "6");
            json2.put("EventName", "Kanatçı Haydar");
            json2.put("EventStatus", "A");
            json2.put("FsqID", "561239");
            json2.put("IsPublic", "False");
            json2.put("LastUpdate", "01.01.0001 00:00:00");
            json2.put("Quota", "8");
            json2.put("UserID", "42");

            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json2.toString()); 

            client.post(arg0.getContext(), PURL, entity, "application/json",
                    new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Activity3.this,response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });

        }
```

**WCF Service**

This is how I handle POST request

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "New")]
    bool SetAllEvents(Stream st);
```

This function calls JSON parser

```
public bool SetAllEvents(Stream s)
    {
        SetEvents se = new SetEvents();

        var data = se.SetNewEvent(s, connStr);
        return true;
    }
```

This is how I parse JSON

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputStream);
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();

            var Jsonobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Events>(json);

            string eventName = Jsonobject.EventName;
```

Comment: What is the error/exception you are seeing?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov actually I dontget any exception or error. No message on Log Cat, also I'm checking service side and there is nothing on logs,it looks like there is no request to service

Comment: I just keep seeing dialogue box and that's all, so making post request doesn't end successfully I think.

Comment: Did you try clearing out all the noise and just trying to send a small json request to the WCF service?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I did however nothing changed. I believe there is no problem on posting, I think there is a problem on parsing JSON on the service side. As you see, I'm sending an entity object in post method and on service side, we are trying to read Stream Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your httppost header for the client side look like? The following may help you:

```
httpost.setEntity(se);
httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

Comment: I set the content type as null and problem was fixed